# .Net Windows Service and Custom Trace Listeners

Tags: c#, windows-services, trace, tracelistener

I have all of my service logic encapsulated in class library.  When I instantiate the class library in a command line app I receive my trace information.

When I instantiate the class in a Windows Service, I see that my Custom trace listener has created the logs directory and start a file, but it stays a 0 KB.

Both applications have this in the .config:

```
 <system.diagnostics>
<switches>
  <add name="PTraceSwitch" value="Verbose" />
</switches>
<trace autoflush="true">
  <listeners>
    <add name="CustomXmlWriterTraceListener" />
    <add name="MyServiceEventListener"  />
    <remove name="Default" />
  </listeners>
</trace>
<sharedListeners>
  <add
     type="CustomUtilities.CustomXmlWriterTraceListener, CustomUtilities"
     name="CustomXmlWriterTraceListener"
     initializeData="Logs\MyService.svclog"
     RollLogAtMidnight="True"
     DateFormat="yyyy.MM.dd"
     MaxFileSizeMB="1"
     CompressLogsOlderThanTimeSpan="1.00:0:00"
     DeleteLogsOlderThanTimeSpan="30.00:00:00"/>

  <add name="MyServiceEventListener"
       type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener"
       initializeData="MyServiceEventLog">
    <filter type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter"
      initializeData="Warning" />
  </add>
</sharedListeners>
```

Comment: Are you missing a `Trace.Flush()`?

Comment: Are you sure the `Logs\MyService.svclog` file is created relative to your exe? Services usually start with `\Windows` or `\Windows\System32` as their working directory.

Comment: @ Rubens Farias, I have it set to Autoflush, and Flush() did not seem to help

Comment: @ Stephen Cleary, Yes, the file is being created in the correct place.

I'll try to attach a debugger to the service and do more digging.  Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: are you perhaps building your service with trace disabled (project properties)?

Comment: Does the account the service is running under have permission to write to that location where the svclog file is being created??

Comment: Thank you for all of the ideas, but I have a work around for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my CustomXmlWriterTraceListener behaves differently when run with a service than a class library or exe.

I added this to my service to debug the main entry point and walk through the init of my listener:

```
Debugger.Launch();
```

The underlying Writer is null when I run my service, it is normally populated during the base constructor.  I used .NET Reflector to see what the XmlWriterTraceListener does.  There is an internal method EnsureWriter().  This method should create the Writer.  I cloned Microsoft's method and added it to my Listener, and all seems to be okay.  My Listener is suitable for a service now.

```
 internal bool EnsureWriter()
    {
        bool flag = true;
        if (Writer == null)
        {
            flag = false;
            if (baseFileName == null)
            {
                return flag;
            }
            Encoding encodingWithFallback = new UTF8Encoding(false);
            string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(baseFileName);
            string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    Writer = new StreamWriter(fullPath, true, encodingWithFallback, 0x1000);
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + fileName;
                    fullPath = Path.Combine(directoryName, fileName);
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!flag)
            {
                baseFileName = null;
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

Comment: i am not sure if what i write now is applicable to this issue, but i was looking for a solution to a similar problem (Writer property of the listener staying null after initialization) and it only dawned on me much later (from posts on the internet) that my service was running from Local Service account, an account with restricted privileges, which of course was forbidden to write to all paths on my PC..